# Error comes while performing any action on file in VS project which is bind with SVN

Tags: svn, ankhsvn

I am getting an error while performing any action on File which in VS project and its bound with SVN.

Whenever I tried to commit,Update,Merge for any action , error comes.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The working copy is corrupted. Backup your uncommitted / unsaved work, checkout a new working copy and copy over your uncommitted changes.